# Ajax request dependent upon which button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I was wondering if anyone could assist with the following. I have two buttons that when clicked need to render a different form, which I would like to achieve with Ajax

```
    <!-- Animal Type -->
   <div class="col-md-6 type-col" data-clicked-status="false">
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-green btn-animal-type" id="dog_rehome_button" data-remote="true">Dog</button>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6 type-col" data-clicked-status="false">
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-green btn-animal-type" id="cat_rehome_button" data-remote="true">Cat</button>
   </div>
```

Im my view I have a div ready for the content to be loaded into, and have this setup

**new.js.erb**

```
$(".rehome_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('/animals/dog_rehome')) %>");
```

So at the moment when either button is clicked the dog_rehome form is rendered.

Ideally though I want to render a different form when clicking on the Cat button.

```
/animals/cat_rehome
```

How can I tell rails to render the corresponding form when its button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#cat_rehome_button').click(function() {
    $(".rehome_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('/animals/cat_rehome')) %>");
});
```

Comment: thanks, when i do this though i get an unrecognized syntax error within my loaded form, so i changed load to html, which works, but i have to click the button twice for it to show the form, each time the button is clicked it requests /animals/new, any ideas ?

Comment: Just so you know, if you use `.html()` and not `.load()`, you're stripping out any JavaScript that may be in the loaded form.  I'd have to see the rest of your code to let you know where that error is coming from.  Is your `form.rehome_form` element emptied when you unload the current form?